# Add images to XCode project without adding the files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

due to my project setup I want to be able to add the images to my project without actually adding the file. Kind of like a header search path if you will. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How will your code load the images?

Comment: This is not a proper way to asking question please put some code and more details about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

just add references only, make sure that checkbox copy files to project directory is not active when you drag and drop images into your project three or using "add files to project" menu option. There is will be the dialog which is contains adding files option, one of them - is to copy files or just add references into your project.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer, and could be deleted or removed if you do not add some more information that could better be used to answer the question.

Comment: Sorry, but I have nothing more to say, answer is equal to question. How to add images into projects without coping.

Comment: Sounds like it answers the question, if you ask me.